# Определение координат здания по нажатию на него

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Как сделать определение координат здания по нажатию на него? (Google Map API android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть [пример кода](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro#sample_code), предоставляемый `Google Play Services SDK`. Используется `SupportMapFragment`.

Метод в `EventsDemoActivity` используется для реализации `OnMapClickListener`.

**EventsDemoActivity:**

```
public class EventsDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity
    implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private TextView mTapTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.events_demo);

        mTapTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tap_text);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMap()
    {
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
        mTapTextView.setText("tapped, point=" + point);
   }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
        mTapTextView.setText("long pressed, point=" + point);
    }
}
```

**XML:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/tap_text"
  android:text="@string/tap_instructions"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Comment: @NikitaER, не за что, отметь ответ )

Answer (score 0):

разбейте вашу проблему на 2 части:

1. Определить координаты клика на карту (Широту и долготу)
2. Определить, что находится по этим координатам